# codeigniter ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, form-submit, preventdefault

i have a form (made through codeigniter) that i want to submit with ajax onClick. Form submits without Ajax and doesnt let me do `event.preventDefault();`

**jQuery file**

```
$('#register_submit').click(function(e){//
   e.preventDefault();
    var first_name = $('#register_form1').val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        async: false, 
        url: base_url+"register/registration_val",   
        data: "register_first_name="+first_name,
        success: function(data){
            $('#inferiz').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){alert('error');}
    }); 

});
```

// Controller works just fine. name register, function that i POST to is registration_val

**HTML file**

```
 <form method="POST" action='<?php echo site_url('/register/registration_val'); ?>' id='register_form' >
   <input type="login" name="register_first_name" id="register_form1">
   <input type='submit' value="Register" id='register_submit'>
 </form>
```

Problem is, when I click on SUBMIT button, jQuery doesnt do its work, instead, form submits itself to the controller and gives out an ERROR message.
I cannot prevent the form from submitting (which i think would solve the problem), the Click event is completely ignored. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the form exist on DOM ready? did you put your code inside the `DOM ready event`?

Comment: your console isn't throwing any errors?  if thats not the only jquery on the page, it could be some other script is broke and just stopping this script from running.

Comment: yes, i have `document.ready(function(){  });`. everything works on js file except the click on form submition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try your luck with the `submit` event instead of `click`:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){//
   e.preventDefault();
    var first_name = $('#register_form1').val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        async: false, 
        url: base_url+"register/registration_val",   
        data: "register_first_name="+first_name,
        success: function(data){
            $('#inferiz').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){alert('error');}
    });     
});
```

If the from has an `id` replace `'form'` with `'#{formId}'`.

**Notes:**

- The code should be inside a DOM ready event callback.
- If the form doesn't exist on DOM ready, you should use delegate event.

Like with this:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var first_name = $('#register_form1').val();    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        async: false, 
        url: base_url+"register/registration_val",   
        data: "register_first_name="+first_name,
        success: function(data){
            $('#inferiz').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){alert('error');}
    });     
});
```

Just replace `body` with a closer **static** element (if there is one) to enhance performance.

**Good Luck!**

Comment: binding on('submit'  worked, thanks! btw, why do you think it didnt work with just $(form).submit when i had document.ready(funciton(){ })  ? or it is not the same thing and i am confised?

Comment: @SemurNabiev. I'll give you a reading assignment, if it's not clear ask again and I'll try to help. [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). read the *Direct and delegated events* paragraph. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you put `return false;` to the end of click event, it should not submit your form to controller..